# Installing Nokogiri with a modified Makefile

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

When I try to create a new rails project on my PowerPC Mac OS X with `ruby-2.4.2` and `rails-5.1`, it started to download and install various gems and during the build step of `nokogiri-1.10` I got

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-array-bounds"
```

during the compilation of libxml2.9.9. I modified the

```
~/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/powerpc-apple-darwin9.8.0/ports/libxml2/2.9.9/libxml2-2.9.9/Makefile
```

to comment out the error causing `-Wno-array-bounds` option and remade the project but it gave the same error again. I guess it's reverting back the original Makefile. How can I install nokogiri with a modified Makefile?

Comment: I think it's very unlikely that editing the gem's makefile is the "right" answer... What led to this attempted workaround? Just a guess, or did you read about it elsewhere? Also, it seems you're editing a file in the `...ruby/2.1.0/gems/...` folder, despite running Ruby 2.4.2 -- what's going on here?

Comment: I think it's more likely you just need to update your gcc version, if possible.

Comment: @TomLord Yes I've noticed that version numbers mismatch (2.4.2 vs 2.1.0) too, but only after I started a new rails project and ran into this error did I notice it. I had installed the 2.4.2 version of ruby from source into the `/usr/local/` folder and the previous version 1.8.6 resides in /usr/bin; that is no ruby-2.1.0 is installed so I wonder how those 2.1.0 numberings came up.

Comment: @TomLord Forgot to mention the gcc version;  it's gcc-4.2.2 but it's no easy task to update it as it's a PowerPC Mac. But anyway, that version of gcc runs quite fine, for example using it I could build the ruby-2.4.2.

Comment: `-Wno-array-bounds` was introduced in gcc 4.6. gcc 4.2.2 does not support that flag. That's why your installation currently is failing. As for why "commenting it out doesn't work" -- I'm not sure. Maybe that error isn't being triggered from where you think it is? I'd start by just trying to upgrade gcc, and install the gem the "normal" way, if possible.

Comment: I've removed ruby-2.4.x installation and installed ruby-2.5.3, all with the gcc-4.2.1 Btw, the ruby-2.1.0 was coming from this line on `.bash_profile`: `export GEM_HOME=~/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0` I've corrected it. But the `gem install rails` still fails with the same `cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-array-bounds"` error. Here are the screenshots from the fail:
![nokogiri-fail01](http://i63.tinypic.com/2z888l5.png)
![nokogiri-fail01](http://i68.tinypic.com/2a5xblv.png)

Comment: ![Screenshot01](http://oi63.tinypic.com/2z888l5.jpg)
Why doesn't it show the images in embedded form. Have no idea.

Comment: Just googling the error leads to a plethora of results indicating that the GCC version is likely the issue. The fact that *something else* installed with this GCC version does not necessarily mean that *this* should install with an old GCC version. Why is it "no easy task" to update the version?

Comment: I agree that having installed other things with this GCC does not necessarily mean that it should be able to install nokogiri too. But in this particular case, that GCC is able to build nokogiri only if that pesky `-Wno-array-bounds` option is removed. Updating GCC is no easy task because there are no official GCC binaries newer than GCC-4.2.3 for this Mac mini. I might try to build one from scratch, though.

Comment: @TomLord Last night I've build GCC-4.6.0 using the Apple-built GCC-4.2.1 with these options: `--disable-libquadmath` and `--disable-multilib` (to prevent GCC from building PPC64 libraries and features which I will never use and causes some trouble anyway) then I tried installing nokorigi the -Wno-array-bounds error's gone but this time `-Wshorten-64-to-32` and `-W-extra-tokens` errors came up. so I've built the ruby again using this new GCC and finally nokogiri got built!

Comment: Hooray Glad you figured it out

Comment: You might write down an answer which summarizes the details.